# Can React replace traditional progressive enhancement techniques?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-enhancement

I am working on a project that already uses React, but only for specific elements of the site. The owner just requested a field on a form **not** rendered by React to become visible only when a checkbox is checked. I know how to do this using native event listeners, and I'm not interested in rewriting the form to be a React component (I'd need identical output that matches the server-side rendering).

Since React is already present, is there a simple way to use it setup a binding between the checkbox value and the visibility of the other field? Basically traditional progressive enhancement but with React handling the state? My research so far suggests React cannot really work with nodes it didn't render.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, it sounds like you should look up [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and just wrap the thing inside a functional component

Comment: But that's reimplementing the output in React with JSX, isn't it? I'm trying to work with the markup provided by the server (from Python). I haven't found any examples of React doing this without basically recreating the form as a full component, which would throw out the Python rendering.

Comment: Since React is data-driven and not DOM-driven (like jQuery) I'm afraid it's not possible without re-writing the relevant parts in React.

Comment: Yeah sounds like you have to. To be fair, I can't really see why it should be difficult. You just take the result of whatever is the provided markup from server and edit few tags so it looks like JSX There are also tools like [html to jsx](https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm)

Comment: I've once done this kind of thing with Vue.js which was quite good, and it was the only time I've ever used Vue.js. I believe it should be easier than with React.

Comment: yeah this is possible, I need to see the relevant checkbox code and the html form field.

Comment: Yes, I have done this with Vue.js and it was very easy since it's meant to drop in to anything. I've only used React in full projects, so I was posting this question to see if I was overlooking something.